# comparing percentile ranks of two normal distributions with 1 std difference in medians

Tags: statistics

We have normal distributions A and B. Distribution B's median is 1 standard deviation to the right of distribution A. What percentile in Distribution A is 98th percentile of distribution B?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is customary give some indication what you have tried and the source of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following example should get you started.

Suppose $X_A \sim Norm(0, 1)$ and $X_B \sim Norm(1,1)$
Then the 98th percentile of $X_B$ is 3.053749. And
$P(X_A \le 3.053794) =  0.99887.$ So the answer is percentile
99.9, in this example. These results are from software;
results from normal tables will be somewhat less precise.

This is for one particular example. Is the answer the same
for other examples that meet your criteria? Look at Z-scores.

In R software, `pnorm(qnorm(.98, 1, 1), 0, 1)` returns 0.99887.